# Why does form_for(@object) do |f| work in the _form.html.erb but not in the index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Ok, So i'm trying to place the form found in the "_form.html.erb" in the  "index.html.erb" of my ruby project crashes with the error

> "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
```

I know that changing the `@customer` to `Customer.new` could fix this but I would like to know why this isn't necessary in one file and it is in another

Why is this happening and how do I make a form that will update the **sqlite db** on the index page.

Comment: did you define @customer in your controller? what did your render partial look like?

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize that I needed to also add the @customer = customer.new. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@customer` is a variable that must be created somewhere in the corresponding controller action. If your `#index` controller action defines a variable by that name, then you'll be able to use it in the view template; otherwise you'll need to create it like this:

```
@customer = Customer.new # (or whatever the value is)
```

When Rails processes a request, it just executes a big (and complex) lump of code that's created from a bunch of different files. First it executes the appropriate controller action, then it executes any Ruby code found inside the corresponding view template. So any variable (or any method name) that is used in the view template, was first defined at some point before that: either in the controller action, or in one of Rails' countless built-in helper files.

Answer (score 0):

When I am using **form_for** in a index or show page I like to do is set it to new

```
<%= form_for Customer.new, url: {controller: "customers", action: "create"} do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

that way there is a object to be created, I also I like to pass in the controller and the action.